# QuickSort Python TypeError: can only assign an iterable

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, quicksort

From my understanding in quicksort is that you pick the right most element as the pivot initially and move elements greater than the pivot to the right of the pivot and elements less than the pivot to the left of the pivot. Once the pivot is moved to right spot lets say in the middle, the array is split in half where you recursively sort the two array halves starting in the beginning and ending before the pivot and starting after the pivot to the end of the array using the same steps as previously stated. I keep getting a type error "TypeError: can only assign an iterable" when assigning the following two lines of code to sort the two array halves.

Problematic code

```
array[:pivot] = quicksort(array[:pivot])
array[pivot+1:] = quicksort(array[pivot+1:])
```

Full Code

```
def quicksort(array):
    
    if len(array) >1 :
        
        low = 0;
        pivot = len(array) -1;
    
        while low < pivot:
            if array[low] > array[pivot]:
        
                tempPivot = array[pivot]
                tempLow = array[low]
                tempPivotPrev = array[pivot-1]
                
                array[pivot] = tempLow
                array[pivot-1] = tempPivot
                array[low] = tempPivotPrev
                
                
                pivot=-1
            else:
                low=+1
                
            array[:pivot] = quicksort(array[:pivot])
            array[pivot+1:] = quicksort(array[pivot+1:])

    
        return array

test = [21, 4, 1, 3, 9, 20, 25, 6, 21, 14]
print quicksort(test)
```

Comment: In the last iteration quicksort returns `None` - and the assignment becomes `array[:1] = None` - that is causing the error. Print `array` right before those recursions.

Comment: What is your base case?

Comment: Put some print statements in - your code it doesn't look like what you described in words. - something like `print(f'low:{low} pivot:{pivot} {array}')` as the first while loop statement, maybe a couple more..   Here is a visual example, it might make it easier to implement - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywWBy6J5gz8

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my comparison logic to compare the pivot and elements was incorrect and I should be recursively sorting the two halves after the while loop.

```
def quicksort(array):

    
    if len(array) >1:
        
        pivot = len(array) - 1
        low = 0

        while low < pivot:
            if array[low]>array[pivot]:
                tempPivot = array[pivot]
                tempLow = array[low]
                array[low] = array[pivot-1]
                array[pivot] = tempLow
                array[pivot-1] = tempPivot
                pivot -= 1
            else:
                low += 1
       
        array[:pivot] = quicksort(array[:pivot])
        array[pivot+1:] = quicksort(array[pivot+1:])
        
    return array
        
            
        

test = [21, 4, 1, 3, 9, 20, 25, 6, 21, 14]
print quicksort(test)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe your quicksort variant, though functionality correct, has performance that is inferior to more common implementations: For each of the, on average, half of the items that are greater than the pivot (assuming a random array) , your version does 5 array reads and 3 array writes whereas most variants can do the same with 3 reads and 2 writes.